# German umlauts in EndpointAddress with net.tcp

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to make instance of class EndpointAddress where parameter contains German umlaut.

*For example*:

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://süd:8001/EmployeeService");
```

It always throws exception that given uri cannot be parsed. I have tried to replace the umlaut with an encoded value, but I get same exception:

> Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.

Did anyone had same problem before?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What was the conversion looking like? What does the exception say?

Comment: `new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://süd:8001/EmployeeService")` works fine for me on .net4.5. Are you using an older version?

Comment: Have you tried enabling  [International Resource Identifier (IRI) parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968786.aspx)? [<iriParsing>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882600.aspx) You could also try enabling  [Internationalized Domain Name (IDN) parsing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb968786.aspx). [<idn>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882553.aspx)

Comment: IDN to ACE would be "xn--sd-xka" instead of "süd": `new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://xn--sd-xka:8001/EmployeeService")`

Comment: @spender. I'm using 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parser probably doesn't know how to work with [internationalized domain names](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (IDN). If you want to have such hostnames, you're going to have to do the Punycode encoding yourself. I haven't used it, but there's a core function [IdnMapping.GetAscii](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.idnmapping.getascii%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) that looks suitable — something like

```
EndpointAddress endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(
    "net.tcp://" + IdnMapping.GetAscii("süd") + ":8001/EmployeeService"
);
```

will perhaps work (forgive me if it doesn't, C# isn't my language).

Comment: Hobbs, thank you for answer.
Now, I'm facing with another problem. I think that cause is same.
Next, I'm trying to create instance of DuplexChannelFactory. I have: _factory = new DuplexChannelFactory<ISomeServiceClass>(new InstanceContext(callbackImplementation), binding, endpointAddress); 
_channel = _factory.CreateChannel(); 
(_channel as ICommunicationObject).Open();
It crashes on Open(). After using IdnMapping I get net.tcp://xn--sd-xka:8001/EmployeeService. After executing Open() it throws CommunicationException with message "No DNS entries exist for host xn--sd-xka.". 
Thank you

Comment: @Nenad that's not the same problem; you just can't connect to a host that doesn't exist. :-P

Answer (score 2):

Just as an extra note. WCF added support for IDN (both for hosting service + WCF client talking to a service with IDN name) in .Net 4.5. This [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh556231.aspx) has some information about this.

So this exception will disappear as soon as you compile your app against .net 4.5

Answer (score 1):

As suggested you have to enable IRI and IDN parsing before using this kind of URI.

Add this to your app.config:

```
 <configuration>
     <uri>
         <idn enabled="All" />
         <iriParsing enabled="true" />
     </uri>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to use

```
string uri = System.Uri.EscapeDataString("net.tcp://süd:8001/EmployeeService");
```

Look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) for further reference.